# How do I connect a Linux machine so that it's the "headphones" to a bluetooth sound device?

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth

The simple version of this is that I have a sound playing device, that normally connects to bluetooth headphones. But instead I want my Linux machine to see that device as a "virtual microphone".

Concretely, this is a ham radio that would normally want a headset. But I want it into my Linux machine so that I can record it as wav files, or process the audio live.

I actually want both directions, ideally. In other words I want to play audio on Linux box to transmit on the radio.

The radio (in title referred to as a "bluetooth sound device") has bluetooth support, expecting to connect to a headset. The Linux machine has bluetooth. E.g. a laptop with built-in bluetooth, but in any case a bluetooth device that can be listed with `hcitool dev`.

So I want to configure the Linux machine to present itself as a headset to the radio, and for the radio to show up as a sound card in Linux. Over bluetooth.

Comment: not really Linux specific  ... the question would be the same if the PC ran MS Windows

Comment: The commands will be entirely different on Linux and Windows. What are you saying will be the same? I need a Linux machine to present itself as a bluetooth headset.

Comment: that is not clearly stated in your post ... the post actually reads like you are asking about wiring ... connecting linux machine to a bluetooth sound device and recording sound ... please edit your post

Comment: @jsotola [This is Thomas's original question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/20076/connecting-linux-to-yaesu-ft3d-via-bluetooth-for-audio-into-direwolf), FYI. Can you or anyone else suggest an edit to this one?

Comment: Can we assume here that **both** the radio and the computer are equipped with Bluetooth? If not, then perhaps there exists a suitable Bluetooth device that could be connected to the radio, using the laptop's Bluetooth?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Yes, the radio (in title referred to as a "bluetooth sound device") has bluetooth support, expecting to connect to a headset. And yes, the Linux machine has bluetooth. E.g. a laptop with built-in bluetooth, but in any case a bluetooth device that can be listed with `hcitool dev`. I welcome suggestions for clarifications to the post itself. No obvious changes come to mind for me, since I already know what I meant. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Put [the comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674067/how-do-i-connect-a-linux-machine-so-that-its-the-headphones-to-a-bluetooth-so#comment1272746_674067) in the question, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Added two paragraphs.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same for another reason. Using the clubhouse app (only available for iOS and Android) I'd like to be able to use Linux to both record from the app (easy w default settings) but also play audio into the app (as a bt microphone for the app) but the phone seems to only recognize my Linux laptop as a speaker, not a headset. I imagine there's a way to configure the Bluetooth daemon. Did you figure this out?